# Angular 6 ngFor card in two columns

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm generating cards in my `*ngFor` div. 
It is generating them vertically (down), but I want angular to generate them horizontally (right).

My idea was to put the class `col-6`, but that doesn't work, it just puts half of the card under each other.

This is the code:

```
<div class="card-body">
<div class="card" *ngFor="let BLA of PACKAGE.blas; let index=index" class="p-1">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{bla.somethingone}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{bla.somethingtwo}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{bla.somethingthree}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I have:

[image]

And I want this:

[image]

I tried adding **col-6** to the classes but it doesn't respond.
How can I achieve this effect ?

Comment: add col-6 to `<div class="card" *ngFor="let BLA of PACKAGE.blas; let index=index" class="p-1">`

Comment: @AliShahbaz I already tried that. It just put the cards in half but they are still under each other, not right next to each other.

Comment: try using style="margin:0%;"

Comment: try using style="float : left;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has nothing to do with Angular, use a `display: flex` on the `card-body` and set `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `flex-direction: row;`:

```css
.card-data {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-data">
  <div class="card">
    card 1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    card 2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    card 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you @Yaser. It was a css problem indeed. I will mark this as answer in a couple of minutes!

Comment: no worries, BTW you can remove the extra css I put there like margin and vertical alignment, that was to show the sample

Answer (score 3):

Change parent div class to `row` and add class `col-6` to card row where your loop running

```
<div class="row">
<div class="card col-6 p-1" *ngFor="let BLA of PACKAGE.blas; let index=index">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{bla.somethingone}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{bla.somethingtwo}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{bla.somethingthree}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

You also have extra `card` div under loop, remove that for clean design.